# MongoDB won't install on Windows 10 (local user)

Tags: mongodb

New to MongoDB and databases in general but while installing MongoDB, the docs say we should use the period for the three inputs while installing (Domain,Name and Password). I did that and got this error,   [i used the period in all 3 inputs as the Docs said but still can't procced, what did i do wrong?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Fbp.png)

Answer (score 4):

To install MongoDB as a local user you can use details as below:

Account Domain: **.** ( dot is the default value )

Account Name: **Your Window's local username**

Account Password: **Your Window's login password**

Note:

1. Your account should be local admin account or change that account to local account.
2. To get your local account name, you can open

> Control Panel\User Accounts\User Accounts

location in your windows explorer.

This link can be helpful [Installing MongoDB as Local User](https://unitrai.com/mongodb-2/mongodb-not-installing-on-windows-10-as-local-user/)

Answer (score 2):

As per [**official**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) docs, Account Name and the Account Password is from your **existing** local user account.

> For an **existing** local user account, specify a period (i.e. .) for
>   the Account Domain and the Account Name and the Account Password for
>   the user.

**alternatively,**

Install mongoDB as **windows service** as shown in below.

[image]

Comment: Funny how i missed that, works when I enter my Windows account username and password

Answer (score 1):

If error is still you need to right click on the MSI file which you downloaded and then select troubleshoot option.

After troubleshoot, it will prompt for the option to install and then it works for me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do much in Account domain just put `dot(.)` And in account name you have to put your PC or local machine name and in password field put your local machine password.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Account Domain be set to the corporate domain in case you have one.
Username will be your id
i.e. in here Control Panel\User Accounts\User Accounts if you see <username>
you should set domain name in Account Domain
Username in Account Name and your password in Account Password

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To get the Account name just go to cmd and type echo %username%
hit Enter you will get Account name and for password use the password you use to login.